# Angular Array instead of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have the following HTML in my view. On the ng-click on the button when I log out the value, the value is an object with numbers as keys in it, instead of an array. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

What gets logged is an Object with a key of 0, would  be accessed like: ObjectName.0

```
              <div class="EquipItems" ng-repeat="(key,value) in Day.equipment track by $index">
                   <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label">
                        {{key}}
                    </div>
                    <select ng-model="value[$index].itemName" ng-options="item as item for item in Equipment.{{key}}">
                        <option value="">Select Option</option>
                    </select>
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <input type="number" ng-model="value[$index].value" placeholder="Amount/Value">
                    </label>

                    <button class="button button-balanced button-outline button-block" ng-click="AddItem(value)">
                      Add {{key}}
                    </button>
               </div>
```

Here is the structure of a Day object.

```
{
                staff : [
                    {
                        name : '',
                        designation : '',
                        timeIn : '',
                        timeOut : ''
                    }
                ],
                vehicles : [
                    {
                        type : '',
                        distance : ''
                    }
                ],
                equipment : {
                    Staff : [
                        {
                            itemName : '',
                            value : ''
                        }
                    ],
                    Equipment : [
                        {
                            itemName : '',
                            value : ''
                        }
                    ],
                    Vehicles : [
                        {
                            itemName : '',
                            value : ''
                        }
                    ],
                    Absorbents : [
                        {
                            itemName : '',
                            value : ''
                        }
                    ],
                    PPE : [
                        {
                            itemName : '',
                            value : ''
                        }
                    ]

                },
                comment :  [
                    {
                        time : '',
                        comment : ''
                    }
                ],
                photos : [
                    {
                        src : '',
                        comment : ''
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Comment: No one can know because we haven't seen your data structure. How is `Day.equipment` structured?

Comment: can you share in question what you see in your console

Comment: Did you mean `ng-click=AddItem(value[$index].value)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just create A demo here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/qm9qwfwg/1/)

In functtion AddItem, I put this:

```
 $scope.AddItem = function(value){
    console.log(value);  // [Object]
    console.log(typeof(value)); //object
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.apply(value)); //[object Array]  still an array
    console.log(value[0]); // get the object
};
```

value is still an array. The element inside the array is Object. Like:

```
{
    itemName : '',
    value : ''
}
```